# How do create an array from the results of a separate function in C?

Tags: arrays, c, eclipse, function

I am working on an Eclipse IDE doing some embedded C programming and I am a bit stuck on how I should proceed. My incomplete code is below -

```
#define ARRAYSIZE 50
void pressure_data(int *var1, int var2)
{
    var2 = ARRAYSIZE;
    int i;
    uint16_t pressure;
    for (i = 0; i < var2; i++)
        {
        pressure = pressure_read();
        var1++;
    }
}

int main();
{
    int array[ARRAYSIZE];
    pressure_data(array, 50);
    return 0;
}
```

- I would like my **'main'** to create a 1D array with a size 50 (defined by ARRAYSIZE)
- Each element of this 1D would be populated by a uint16_t value 'pressure' which is assigned by a separate function called **'pressure_read();'**
- The loop in the **'pressure_data'** function would capture a new value of 'pressure' which would then fill the next index of the 1D array in 'main' and so on until the array contains 50 different 'pressure' values

Currently, this code will capture 50 different values of 'pressure' and print them into the terminal on Eclipse but I have omitted those lines for simplicity's sake.

What is the best method of passing a result of a function **'pressure_data'**, into each index of an array in my main?

I am relative beginner when it comes to C but have been taking some time to learn and understand using pointers as I know they are often used in conjunction with arrays.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why have you tagged the completely unrelated language C#?

Comment: As for your problem, it's rather basic and should be taught be any decent book, class or online-tutorial. Perhaps if you *don't* do it in a separate function, do you know how to set each element of the array then? What makes you think it would be different inside another function?

Comment: `var1[i] = pressure_read();`, and consider using more descriptive names for your parameters. There's also no point in passing the length if you're immediately going to overwrite the value inside the function. If your data is unsigned you should also make the array type unsigned.

Comment: dumb question, but why not `int[] pressure_data(...)` and make `pressure_data` return the whole populated array?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, to be honest I'm entirely sure why I felt the requirement that there should be a separate function. Could this all be accomplished more simply with just my 'main'? (also removed c# tag)

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have size limit of fifty on your array, you might simplify things in your function calls.  Following is one example of how you might perform your task.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRAYSIZE 50

typedef unsigned short uint16_t;

uint16_t pressure_read()
{
    /* For now just return an integer */
    return 15;
}

void pressure_data(uint16_t var1[])
{

    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++)
    {
        var1[i] = pressure_read();
    }
}

int main()
{
    uint16_t array[ARRAYSIZE];
    pressure_data(array);

    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("Pressure: %d\n", array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that in the function, the reference to a one-dimensional array is made in lieu of an integer pointer.  Both are quite valid.  The usage of the "[]" designation is just a point of preference.  But this allows for some simplification of the population of the array.

Give that a try and see if this fulfils the spirit of your project.